# subPathExpr for parallel pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We have parallel jobs on EKS and we would like the jobs to write to `hostPath`.

We are using `subPathExpr` with environment variable as according to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-expanded-environment). However, after the run, the `hostPath` contains only the one folder probably due to racing condition from the parallel jobs and whichever job get hold of the `hostPath`.

We are on Kubernetes 1.17. Is `subPathExpr` meant for this use case of allowing parallel jobs to write to the same `hostPath`? What are other options to allow parallel jobs to write to host volume?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: gatling-job
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 300 # delete after 5 minutes
  completions: 5
  parallelism: 5
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: "Never"
      containers:
        - name: gatling
          image: GATLING_IMAGE_NAME
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name     
          volumeMounts:
            - name: perftest-results
              mountPath: /opt/gatling/results
              subPathExpr: $(POD_NAME)
      volumes:
      - name: perftest-results
        hostPath:
          path: /data/perftest-results
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested with a simple job template as below, and files were created in respective folder and worked as expected.

Will investigate the actual project. Closing for now.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: subpath-jobs
  labels:
    name: subpath-jobs
spec:
  completions: 5
  parallelism: 5
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: "Never"
      containers:
        - name: busybox
          image: busybox
          workingDir: /outputs
          command: [ "touch" ]
          args: [ "a_file.txt" ]
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name     
          volumeMounts:
            - name: job-output
              mountPath: /outputs
              subPathExpr: $(POD_NAME)
      volumes:
      - name: job-output
        hostPath:
          path: /data/outputs
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

```sh
# ls -R /data
/data:
outputs

/data/outputs:
subpath-jobs-6968q  subpath-jobs-6zp4x  subpath-jobs-nhh96  subpath-jobs-tl8fx  subpath-jobs-w2h9f

/data/outputs/subpath-jobs-6968q:
a_file.txt

/data/outputs/subpath-jobs-6zp4x:
a_file.txt

/data/outputs/subpath-jobs-nhh96:
a_file.txt

/data/outputs/subpath-jobs-tl8fx:
a_file.txt

/data/outputs/subpath-jobs-w2h9f:
a_file.txt
```

Comment: On further deep dive found out the pod affinity had a typo. Works as expected after fix.